# Caliburn.Micro Create Combobox Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm quite new to WPF and as new to Caliburn.Micro.
What I'm trying to do is create a combobox dynamically.
Essentially I'm trying to create an auto complete type textbox, but I can't seem to figure out how to either create a combobox dynamically, or attach to a combobox that is already in the xaml so that I can change its properties.

My XAML is as follows:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="customerNameTxt" Width="150" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" cal:Message.Attach="[Event TextChanged]=[customerNameTxt_TextChanged()]" />
    <ComboBox Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding DropDownSource, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</StackPanel>
```

As you can see I am binding to populate the combobox - I have this working perfectly, as well as changing with the user typing into the textbox. 
I'd just like to either be able to change the properties on the combobox, or create it dynamically which would then give me access to all the properties I need. 
I'm using Caliburn.micro so need to get at the combobox from the ShellModelView.cs file.

Any help with this would be great.

UPDATE: Thanks to the idea's to try use the WPFToolkit AutoCompleteBox. I managed to get this to work quite easily which is great, except now the code I had in my ViewModel no longer retrieves the value of the AutoCompleteBox, using Caliburn.micro.  After a bit of playing I figured it out - I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing this, but it does work for me. If this is not the best method I'd be interested in hearing of other ways of doing this.

Here is my XAML:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="customerNameTxt" ItemsSource="{Binding DropDownSource}" IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged]=[Action customerNameTxt_SelectionChanged($eventargs)]" />
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public void customerNameTxt_SelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindObj obj = e.AddedItems[0] as BindObj;
        if (null != obj)
        {
            customerNameTxt = obj.Text;
        }
    }
```

Now my property customerNameTxt is set as it was before.

Any tips of better techniques would be great. As I said I'm new to this WPF stuff so still learning a lot.

Thanks,

Mudders

Comment: What properties on the ComboBox do you need to modify other than the items displayed?  Why aren't you using a prebuilt autocomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have access to the view from your view model in Caliburn.Micro. You can either override `OnViewLoaded` in your view model, or call `GetView`

```
protected override void OnViewLoaded(object view)
{
   base.OnViewLoaded(view);
}
```

Here, you can cast the view object to your view type, and call `FindName("controlName")` to get the instance of you `ComboBox`.

However, why are you not using one of the already available implementations of an auto-complete text box? For example there is one included in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I've installed the WPF Toolkit for .Net4.0 but I can't see the AutoCompleteBox in there. As far as I can tell (and I may be completely wrong in this) the AutoCompleteBox is dependent on .Net3.5?